# sim 900 sending wrong sms -" Ü " to mobile phone from arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

i am having a problem while sending sms from arduino to a specific number. cell phone getting sms but every time it gets same unicode -" Ü " . plz help us

```
//--------------------------
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(2, 3);

void setup()
{
    mySerial.begin(115200);  
    mySerial.print("\r");
    delay(1000);                    
    mySerial.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");    
    delay(20000);

    mySerial.print("AT+CMGS=\"+91..........\"\r");    

    delay(20000);
    mySerial.print("Hello!\r");   //The text for the message
    delay(10000);
    mySerial.write(0x1A);  //Equivalent to sending Ctrl+Z 
}

void loop()
{

}
```

Comment: So you try to send "Hello!", but receive "Ü"?

Comment: yahhh...do you know the reason?

Comment: `Ü` in SMS has the same value (0x5E) as `^` in ASCII. Nothing helpful there. The delays seem a bit long to me. Try lowering those.

Comment: which delay ? is it after ' mySerial.print("Hello!\r") ' ?

Comment: The 20000 and 10000 ones. Waiting 10 or 20 seconds is extremely long.